# How to show previous activity progressively when closing another activity? (similar to Google Photos app in Android when user swipe down on photo)

Tags: android, animation, google-photos

In Google Photos app on Android, when the user taps on a photo, the photo opens in full screen. Then the user has 4 swiping options:

1. SwipeUp, a slider shows with the photo metadata
2. SwipeLeft, the user goes to the next photo
3. SwipeRight, the user goes to the previous photo
4. SwipeDown, the user goes to the previous screen

The effect I am searching for is point #4, the more the user swipes away, the previous activity (which is the album in this case) shows progressively in the background (from black background to more and more transparent background).

In addition to that, if the user brings back the photo to the center of the screen, the background goes back to its previous color (which was black) and the previous activity slowly disappears.

Here's a screenshot of what I am talking about that I took when sliding down around 150dp:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How have you determined that these are independent activities, instead of fragments or just views?

Comment: It might be fragment or a view, I have no idea, I just wanted to know how it was done, that's all

Comment: The title bar looks actually as if it is another activity, as seen in the screenshot